# JavaCard and T=1 protocol: distinguish between APDU cases

Tags: javacard

In case of T=0 protocol, the TPDU of case 1 & case 2 APDUs
and case 3 and case 4 APDUs are the same,
therefore, in the case of T=0 protocol from the smart card
side it is not possible to distinguish between case 1&2 and
case 3&4 APDUs.
In fact, it is not even possible to distinguish between
case 2 & 3 APDU, unless smart card tries to read the data bytes, which will lead to failure if the actual APDU send by the terminal was case 2 APDU.

However, since in T=1 protocol the TPDU corresponds to APDU
the card knows to which case the APDU received belongs.

The question is does the Java Card API provides any means in case of T=1 protocol to:

1. know if the received APDU is data APDU and hence setIncomingAndReceive() can be called safely;
2. read the Le byte from case 4 APDU;
3. know if Le byte was actually received from the terminal (in the ambiguous case where P3 in APDU buffer is 0x00).

Answer (score 2):

> **1. know if the received APDU is data APDU and hence setIncomingAndReceive() can be called safely**

Now this is an interesting one; it seems that `getIncomingLength` could be used for that:

> the incoming byte length indicated by the Lc field in the APDU header. Return 0 if no incoming data (Case 1)

but it says itself in the exception description that:

> `APDUException.ILLEGAL_USE` if `setIncomingAndReceive()` not called or if `setOutgoing()` or `setOutgoingNoChaining()` previously invoked.

And for `setIncomingAndReceive()` you can read that:

> This method should only be called on a case 3 or case 4 command, otherwise erroneous behavior may result.

There seems to be a catch 22 here; I'll ask one of my resources on how to deal with this. In the mean time, it is unlikely (but not impossible) that `setIncomingAndReceive` or `getIncomingLength` throws an exception for case 1 or 2 APDUs.

---

> **2. read the Le byte from case 4 APDU**

Well, yes, by reading the Nc value, then progress through the received bytes to get to the Le byte or bytes that follow the command. But generally it is easier to use Ne (the actual length rather than the encoding of the length) by calling `setOutgoing` which returns:

> ```
> Ne, the expected length of response
> ```

---

> **3. know if Le byte was actually received from the terminal (in the ambiguous case where P3 in APDU buffer is 0x00)**

If P3 = 0x00 then P3 **is** the Le byte as far as I know. I don't see how that is ambiguous. Lc is prohibited from having this value.

---

Notes:

- most APDU commands have a pre-described format, so you know in advance (during processing of the APDU using the `process` method) if you should get a specific case - you can throw an exception you do not;
- I've referenced Java Card 3.0.5 because it is available online and because it correctly distinguises between Nc, Lc, Ne and Le - the interface is however not different from earlier versions.

Comment: Regarding 3rd point: the question is about distinguishing between case 1 APDU (where Le is not sent) and case 2 APDU (where Le is set to 0x00). AFAIK, in both cases you will read 0x00 from apdu.buffer[P3]. So is there any another distinguisher available?

Comment: I don't think so, but may I ask in which protocol this issue arises? I can think of one (rather stupid) instance where you can either have no *command data* and none in the other (SELECT by File ID with P1 = 00 without identifier). In general you should be able to *know* if there is command or response data depending on INS (and possibly P1/P2). And yeah, ISO/IEC 7816-4 is horrible in separating the transport and application layers; basically *it doesn't*; this is why issues like these keep popping up. Note that you could argue that always sending an Le is valid for no response data.

Comment: Many implementations allow for an Le even if there is no response data expected. Unfortunately this is up for discussion - it's the wrong APDU/ISO "case" for many command but nowhere it is said you *have* to return response data.

Comment: Beware that `P3` of `0x00` means zero for *case 1* command, but 256 for *case 2* command. An interesting read is Java Card Runtime Environment Specification, section "APDU Class". +1 for the fact that commands should have their *ISO case* specified

Comment: No, P3 (which notion is not present in ISO/IEC 7816-4) is *absent* for case 1 command (no command or response data).

Comment: You are right and I am wrong (again). In `T=1` only four bytes are transmitted inside the *Information field* for *case 1* command APDUs...I got fooled by `T=0` where my statement holds. Another day on SO, another lesson...